# can't get worksheet name from tables

Tags: phpexcel, worksheet

I need a worksheet name from database table , but my code just print the array and not fetch the string or names from database.  how to return the string in setTitle() function.

```
$query = "select name from campaigns WHERE clients_id='66'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){   
 //if ($row['name'] !== $prevName) {
 $newsheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
 $newsheet->setTitle($row['name']);
 }
```

Comment: `setTitle()` won't return a string containing the worksheet title, it returns a Worksheet object.... that's what it's supposed to do, it's the documented return, and that's what it does.... if you need to return the title of a worksheet, you use the worksheet object's `getTitle()` method

Comment: i used getTitle(). doesn't help me. foreach($row as $title){
 
$newsheet->getTitle($title);
//newsheet->getTitle($title['name']);
//print_r ($title);
}